# Item in javascript array outputting undefined instead of actual value when used with a attr function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array with a different image names. The idea is to fade an image out then change the image name and finally change the image back in, so it looks like every time the image fades a different image shows up.However every time I do a name change rather than outputting a value from the array it outputs the word "undefined"... When I loop through the array and colsole.log the values, everything works ok, but if I try to do the code below, the "undefined" value shows instead of the array value.

Here is my code.

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div id="face">
            <img src="face.png">

        </div>
        <div id="bar">
            <div id="left">
                <img id="leftPic" src="cherry.png"/>

            </div>

            <div id="center">
                <img id="centerPic" src="seven.png"/>
            </div>

            <div id="right">
                <img id="rightPic" src="bar.png"/>
            </div>

            </div>

            <div style="clear:both;"></div>



            <button id="spinIt">Spin</button>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#spinIt").click(function(){

            var fruits = ["banana","bar","cherry", "grape", "lemon", "melon", "orange", "seven", "winner"];


            for (idx = 0; idx < fruits.length; idx++) { 
                $("#leftPic").fadeOut().fadeIn("slow",function(){
                    $("#leftPic").attr("src",fruits[idx]+".png");
                });
            }



        });
    </script>
```

Comment: the for loop will be done before the fadeOut and fadeIn is complete.

Comment: Your fades are queued up and the for loop completes before the fades are done fading, so they all refer to `fruits[9]` which is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a closure to fix this:

```
var temp = function(fruit)
{
    $("#leftPic").fadeOut().fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $("#leftPic").attr("src",fruit+".png");
    });
};

for (idx = 0; idx < fruits.length; idx++) { 
    temp(fruits[idx]);
}
```

Try something like that...check out this for more on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (idx = 0; idx < fruits.length; idx++) { 
    (function(idx)
        $("#leftPic").fadeOut().fadeIn("slow",function(){
            $(this).attr("src",fruits[idx]+".png");
        });
    })(idx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   $("#spinIt").click(function () {

       var fruits = ["banana", "bar", "cherry", "grape", "lemon", "melon", "orange", "seven", "winner"];
       var idx = 0;

       function switchImage() {
           $("#leftPic").fadeOut().fadeIn("slow", function () {
               $("#leftPic").attr("src", fruits[idx] + ".png");
               idx++;
               if (idx < fruites.length) {
                   switchImage();
               }

           });
       }
       switchImage();

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this method of using the for loop, if the value is undefined it wont continue

```
$("#spinIt").click(function () {
    var fruits = ["banana", "bar", "cherry", "grape", "lemon", "melon", "orange", "seven", "winner"], fruit;
    for (var i = 0; fruit = fruits[i]; i++) {
        $("#leftPic").fadeOut().fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $("#leftPic").attr("src", fruit + ".png");
        });
    }
});
```